# How to get post response from post data in iframe angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a form that has been called using an iframe for ezidebit payment, now when that form is submitted I want to catch a response from where the iframe was called
Please, anyone, help me out...
I tried with many solutions included jquery in angular but nothing worked.

Below is the sample for iframe

```html
<iframe scrolling="no" style="height: 1000px; width: 450px; border: 0;" src="https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/V3-5/SecureEntryForm?claims=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%3D%3D&signature=giKlU1YE64gI%2FR0d2nZQkACN5Ijp32x95jZEyrdSe3o%3D"></iframe>
```

The above HTML automatically loads the form and in chrome, I am not able to see the response but in firefox, I can see the response but how to get response data from chrome?

[image]

below are the solutions which i tried by passing id to iframe:

// Call open edge to start loading in the iframes.

```js
SetupOpenEdgeEziDebit(
  this.onTokenSuccess,
  this.onTokenError
);
```

// another with jquery many more

```js
$('#iframe').load((data: any): void => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: As it's a cross-domain iframe, what you're attempting to do is not possible. You are blocked from accessing third-party content through an iframe by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: how to resolve this? but in firefox i am able to see the response

Comment: @vinuta I am also finding solution for this. please let me know if you will get solution.

Comment: sure @Dakopatel